# What is syntax of bool in arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-999999

I want to extract specific values of raster layer. Use codes as follows:

```
attExtract=arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes(outraster,'VALUE==8 | \
                                            VALUE==9 | VALUE==10 | VALUE==16')
```

system hint the SQL is invalid:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
Failed to execute (ExtractByAttributes).
```

How to write the operation bool code?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
attExtract=arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes(outraster,'VALUE IN (8, 9, 10, 16)')
```

Answer (score -1):

I try `"VALUE>=8 AND VALUE<=10 OR VALUE=16"`. It's OK! equal operator is `=`, not `==`.
 Reference the [SQL site](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL%20reference)